# Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) of a specific exponential function

Tags: self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference

I'm am using the Casella, Berger 2nd edition textbook and I am working on problem 7.17, which is provided below,
[image]

I am able to get the solutions for parts a and b without too many issues, however, part c is throwing me for a slight loop. The solution for part c is as follows,
[image]

I understand that for part a) $\hat{\theta}=1$ and that when $X_2=1 \implies Z=0$ however I am not able to see how they got the mle to be $\hat{\theta}=\infty$. Given the density from part b is $f_z(z)=e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}} \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}, z\ge0$ and when we let $Z=0$ we have that $$f_z(z)=e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}}$$. So my question is how does $\hat{\theta}=\infty$?

Thank you for the help.

Adding information for part b, 
[image]

Comment: I went ahead and added the information for the calculation to obtain the pdf of Z. It could be that I am also misunderstanding the notation that is used. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: What value of $\theta$ maximizes $e^{-1/\theta}$?  (It is called the *maximum* likelihood estimator...)